# How do I close a UISearchDisplayController programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to close my UISearchDisplayController when the user clicks the "Search" button since I'm loading new data from the web. How do I close the controller programatically? I already have the proper method called, but don't know how to do it.

I thought that the below would work, but I'm wrong.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.searchDisplayController finalize];
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you very much.. working great and helpful in 2012 too :)

Comment: this didn't work for me. I said once user tap somewhere in -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];} But this did not let it go away. This method got called but no result.

Comment: Perfect.  I'm using this in viewWillDisappear. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you set active to false on main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func setActive(_ visible: Bool,
  animated animated;: Bool)
```

If you are using swift.

Comment: Actually, for Swift the property is `active`